# Error while loading related data in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting below error, while loading the related data (coursepages of a course).

**Error**

> MySqlException: Unknown column 'c.Coursepages.CoursepageId' in 'field list'

**Point of failure :**

```
var course = await _context.Courses.Include(c => c.Coursepages)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Url == courseUrl);
```

**Application DB Context :**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("courses");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id).HasName("idx_Courses_Id");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Url).HasName("uk_Url").IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("int(11)");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Coursepage>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("coursepages");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CourseId).HasName("idx_CoursePages_CourseId");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.LessonId).HasName("idx_CoursePages_LessonId");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TopicId).HasName("idx_CoursePages_TopicId");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CourseId, e.LessonId, e.TopicId }).HasName("uk_CourseId_LessonId_TopicId").IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("int(11)");
            entity.Property(e => e.CourseId).HasColumnType("int(11)");
            entity.Property(e => e.LessonId).HasColumnType("int(11)").HasDefaultValueSql("'0'");
            entity.Property(e => e.TopicId).HasColumnType("int(11)").HasDefaultValueSql("'0'");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Course)
                .WithMany(p => p.Coursepages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CourseId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CoursePages_Courses_CourseId");
        });
```

**Course Model**

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        Coursepages = new List<Coursepage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Coursepage> Coursepages { get; set; }
}
```

**CoursePages Model :**

```
public partial class Coursepage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

> Note : I am using ASP.Net Core 2.0 with MySQL using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL driver.

Comment: Hi, down-voter. Can you please drop a comment with the reason / justification ? It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is :

> public List < Coursepage > Topics { get; set; }

EntityFramework tries to map this property onto the database, and assumes the primary key as "CoursepageId" which it doesn't find anywhere in the db.

> Any property which is not directly mapped to Database should be labeled with **NotMapped** attribute.

So the **Coursepages Model** must be like :

```
public partial class Coursepage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

      //  If current page is a Lesson Page
      [NotMapped]
      public List<Coursepage> Topics { get; set; }
}
```

**Note :** Import the namespace **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema** to use **NotMapped** attribute.

References :

- [Including & Excluding Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties)